# assembly language problems while working with msdos files coding

Tags: assembly, assemblies, inline-assembly

**as readme.txt file is saying**: you should link your **BIOS** to accomodate the call back to the bios at the end of **SYSINIT**. if you no need for this call, simply find a far RET and label it RE_INIT and declare it public.
my poblem begins here:

### i am very confused that i should search for **far RET** in **SKELIO.ASM** file and label it RE_INIT (but where should i place this label?) or i should go for "SYSINIT.ASM" file and search **far RET** there and label it RE_INIT (how?).please see the code below for some portion of both files. i must mention that skelio.asm file is for bios and sysinit.asm file is for system initialization.

**SKELIO.ASM**: code as follows

```
; I/O system for Version 2.x of MSDOS.

;This BIOS designed to be linked with the SYSINIT module provided by
;Microsoft

BIOSIZ  EQU     4096            ;Size of BIOS in bytes.
BIOSIZS EQU     100H            ;Size of BIOS in Paragraphs.
ANSI    EQU     0               ;Ansi switch.

;Additional Information for the ALTOS machine.

QSIZE   EQU     100             ;Input queue size.
BIOSSEG EQU     0C0H            ;I/O system segment.
MAX_MEM EQU     4000H           ;Memory size in paragraphs.

; Constants for commands in Altos ROM.

ROM_CONSTA      EQU     01      ;Return status AL of console selected in CX.
ROM_CONIN       EQU     02      ;Get char. from console in CX to AL
ROM_CONOUT      EQU     03      ;Write char. in DL to console in CX.
ROM_PMSG        EQU     07      ;Write string ES:DX to console in CX.
ROM_DISKIO      EQU     08      ;Perform disk I/O from IOPB in ES:CX.
ROM_INIT        EQU     10      ;Returns boot console and top memory ES:DX.

;Things needed to communicate with SYSINIT

EXTRN   SYSINIT:FAR                   ;The entry point of SYSINIT
EXTRN   CURRENT_DOS_LOCATION:WORD     ;Where the DOS is when SYSINIT called
EXTRN   FINAL_DOS_LOCATION:WORD       ;Where I want SYSINIT to put the DOS
EXTRN   DEVICE_LIST:DWORD             ;Pointer to the DEVICE list.
EXTRN   MEMORY_SIZE:WORD              ;Size in paragraphs of Physical 
;memory.
EXTRN   DEFAULT_DRIVE:BYTE            ;Default Drive to use when system 
;booted
EXTRN   BUFFERS:BYTE                  ;Number of default buffers.
                                  ; Leave as is and SYSINIT uses only 2.

CODE    SEGMENT
ASSUME  CS:CODE,DS:CODE,ES:CODE,SS:CODE

    ORG     0               ;Starts at an offset of zero.

INIT:   JMP     HWINIT

    PAGE

    SUBTTL  Device driver tables.
------- and so on
--------SKELIO.ASM code ends here
------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYSINIT.ASM: code as follows

TITLE   BIOS SYSTEM INITIALIZATION

FALSE   EQU     0
TRUE    EQU     NOT FALSE
IBMVER     EQU     FALSE
IBM        EQU     IBMVER
IBMJAPVER  EQU     FALSE                ; If TRUE set KANJI true also
MSVER      EQU     TRUE 
ALTVECT    EQU     FALSE                ; Switch to build ALTVECT version
HIGHMEM    EQU     FALSE
KANJI      EQU     FALSE

    IF      IBMVER OR IBMJAPVER
NOEXEC  EQU     TRUE
    ELSE
NOEXEC  EQU     FALSE
    ENDIF

; Set to agree with those in DOST:MSHEAD.ASM, ALTVECT version only
MAJOR_VERSION   EQU      2
MINOR_VERSION   EQU     0B  ;2.11

DOSSIZE EQU     5000H

; Internal DOS data returned by DOSINIT

SYSINITVAR  STRUC
DPBHEAD     DD      ?                   ; Pointer to head of DPB-FAT list
sft_addr    DD      ?                   ; Pointer to first FCB table
; The following address points to the CLOCK device
BCLOCK      DD      ?
; The following address is used by DISKSTATCHK it is always
; points to the console input device header
BCON        DD      ?                   ; Console device entry points
NUMIO       DB      0                   ; Number of disk tables
MAXSEC      DW      0                   ; Maximum allowed sector size
BUFFHEAD    DD      ?                   ; Head of buffer queue
DEVHEAD     DD      ?
SYSINITVAR  ENDS

    INCLUDE DOSSYM.ASM
    INCLUDE DEVSYM.ASM

    IF      NOT IBM
    IF      NOT IBMJAPVER

    ENDIF
    ENDIF

SYSINITSEG      SEGMENT PUBLIC 'SYSTEM_INIT'
------------------------------ and so on
------------------------------ and so on
LOCSTACK LABEL BYTE

    CALL    MSDOS
    MOV     WORD PTR [DOSINFO+2],ES ; SAVE POINTER TO DOS INFO
    MOV     WORD PTR [DOSINFO],DI

    IF      NOT IBM
    IF      NOT IBMJAPVER
    CALL    RE_INIT                 ; Re-call the BIOS <-----**problem**
    ENDIF
    ENDIF

    STI
    CLD

    IF      HIGHMEM
    PUSH    DS
    MOV     BX,DS
    ADD     BX,10H
    MOV     ES,BX
    PUSH    CS
    POP     DS
    XOR     SI,SI
    MOV     DI,SI
    MOV     CX,OFFSET SYSSIZE + 1
    SHR     CX,1                    ; Divide by 2 to get words
```

### sysinit.asm code ends here

i am trying to link skelio.obj, sysinit.obj and sysimes.obj together
so that i will get ms dos exe file, and i will be able to run ms dos
using it.
thanks.please mention i should search skelio.asm file for a FAR RET and
label it RE_INIT or i should do same with sysinit.asm file.

Comment: At the time of MS-DOS 2.x Microsoft didn't yet know that all successful DOS computers would be IBM PC compatible. So they apparently had an option to use a separate BIOS, instead of the one (presumably non-compliant) present in the machine. You are doing "historic research" at the level of  "light a fire in the cave without advanced technology like rubbing two sticks together". Unless you are writing an academic paper for the Computer History Museum, this code is not really useful for anything.

Comment: @BoPersson Wow.. you must be old! But you are also wise. Really interesting..